# File comparison Ran out of memory

Tags: ruby, file, unix

Hi i am using this code - but for files > 8 Million rows of lines - 2 files passed as text input, the memory runs out. How can i compare both text files which are more than 30 Million lines maybe.

```
fileA1 = ARGV[0]
fileA2 = ARGV[1]

if ARGV.length != 2
  raise 'Send Two files pls'
end
cmd = "sort #{fileA1} > Sorted.txt"
`#{cmd}`
aFile = File.open("Sorted.txt", "r");
bFile = File.open(fileA2, "r").readlines;
fileR = File.open("result.txt", "w")

p aFile.class
p bFile.class
p bFile.length

aFile.each do |e|
  if(! bFile.include?(e) )
    p 'Able to get differences:' + e.to_s
    fileR.write('Does not Include:' + e)
  end
end
```

additional coding i tried without luck.

```
counterA = counterB = 0
aFile = File.open("Sample1 - Copy.txt", "r");
bFile = File.open("Sample2.txt", "r");
file1lines = aFile.readlines
file2lines = bFile.readlines


file1lines.each do |e|
if(!file2lines.include?(e))
puts e
 else
p "Files include these lines:"
end
end
stopTime = Time.now
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to find which lines in the first file aren't in the second? Is the second file sorted?

Comment: comparing 30Million lines is more like a task for a database. Good luck.

Comment: Hi this is preliminary code. I am trying to find mismatches between two big data files from hadoop and AWS. Once i find mismatches - developer will need to analyze what and why is the mismatch and i need to send him some details for the lines. I already tried Diff also. Diff runs out of memory. I am trying to use cucumber and run test cases for to compare various batch run output files.

Comment: I cant create databases randomly and load data as of now. We are doing testing. For every cucumber test case the out put file will be different. How will i do that if i use Data base? should i run SQL to compare the difference ? or Join query ?. Will it be too slow ? as I need to load two files atleast. And then run the query.

Comment: So the expected and desired case is that the text lines would be identical from both sources?  If so, then a more practical test might be to compare a more manageable number of lines, maybe even random lines in the 2 files.  `File.foreach` iterates over the lines in the file without saving them in memory, so you could use that to find lines in the random positions in the 2 files and compare them.  Or just compare all lines and raise an error on the first difference.

Comment: Keith sorry - i tried that also . fgt to mention. I cannot run it too slow as part of test automation. It ran overnight and more for around 8 million lines in my laptop. I can try pushing it to a unix server and try otherwise. and let you know, but the actual files size is around 30 million.  what i tried was a couple of variations.  Loop around each line of outer file and loop around inner file. 2nd - loop around outer file and push alllines into array for second file - threw out of memory too.

Comment: Can you suggest how to read a file in ruby line by line . and for next comparison, continue comparing from that line. Example - read line from file a, read fileB in a loop, compare found, read line 2 from file a, continue reading from say, line 101 [ 100 is previous match for line 1 file 1] in file B etc

Comment: Thank you for your comments that help to explain the question.  It's great that you're trying to help those who want to help you.  The question would be greatly improved if you were to edit it to incorporate those comments (there's an "edit" link just below the question's text).  We want the question to stand on its own merit.

Comment: @deepz1k Looping through all the lines in 1 file for each line of another will definitely be unmanageable. (Did I understand you right?) With testing sometimes we need to sacrifice thoroughness for speed; maybe setting sights lower would be a good idea? Or, rather than running a test on demand, have a constantly running process that compares the data as it is logged?  Would finding the first difference be totally useless?  The script below works for that, and illustrates the use of enums from which to read a line at a time from both files into memory.

Comment: @deepz1k I notice that you are very new to SO.  Welcome!  Please read this if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi Keith Thanks a lot. I saw your comment and I accepted it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that will analyze 2 text files, reporting the first difference, or a difference in the number of lines, or success.

***NOTE: THE CODE HERE IS TRUNCATED.  PLEASE GO TO https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/1d043fdf7b685d9692f0181ad68c6307 FOR THE COMPLETE SCRIPT!***

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

raise "Syntax is first_diff  file1  file2" unless ARGV.size == 2

FILE1, FILE2 = ARGV

ENUM1 = File.new(FILE1).to_enum
ENUM2 = File.new(FILE2).to_enum


def build_unequal_error_message(line_num, line1, line2)
"Difference found at line #{line_num}:
#{FILE1}: #{line1}
#{FILE2}: #{line2}"
end


def build_unequal_line_count_error_message(line_count, file_exhausted)
  "All lines up to line #{line_count} were identical, " \
  "but #{file_exhausted} has no more text lines."
end


def get_line(file_enumerator)
  file_enumerator.next.chomp
end


def has_next(enumerator)
  begin
    enumerator.peek
    true
  rescue StopIteration
    false
  end
end


# Returns an analysis of the results in the form of a string
# if a compare error occurred, else returns nil.
def error_text_or_nil

  line_num = 0

  loop do
    has1 = has_next(ENUM1)
    has2 = has_next(ENUM2)

    case
      when has1 && has2
        line1 = get_line(ENUM1)
        line2 = get_line(ENUM2)

        if line1 != line2
          return build_unequal_error_message(line_num, line1, line2)
        end
      when !has1 && !has2
        return nil  # if both have no more values, we're done
      else # only 1 enum has been exhausted
        exhausted_file = has1 ? FILE2 : FILE1
        not_exhausted_file = exhausted_file == FILE1 ? FILE2 : FILE1
        return build_unequal_line_count_error_message(line_num, exhausted_file)
    end

    line_num += 1
  end

  puts "Lines processed successfully: #{line_num}"
end


result = error_text_or_nil

if result
  puts result
  exit -1
else
  puts "Compare successful"
  exit 0
end
```

Comment: Hi Keith it took me some time to understand this. Now where do we change so it summarizes  the entire file . Our tests run in jenkins and over night, we don't want the test to stop. morning we need to analyze all differences.

Comment: Keith your Code was Freaking freeking Good !!! OMG. Performance was minimum 50% faster. I Love it. I tried to up vote but it is not allowing me. Is there any way you have built code for removing duplicates as such. I have duplicate removal programs my programmers built, but I am guessing they cant be as expert like you showed with above example.

Comment: @deepz1k Thanks for the kind words!  I'm afraid I can't be too helpful beyond this.  At this point it's a comp sci / algorithms issue that is, I think, way more complex than my script.  For example, I think determining the distance of the difference and when they sync up again is not simple. I suppose one could study the source code for `diff` to see how they do it.

Comment: Regarding eliminating duplicates, that requires processing the entire set of records, which would require some kind of huge data structure in memory, or some kind of data store (e.g. Mongo DB, Kafka, an RDBMS).  Could you modify your test to spot check, that is, for example, check random 5 minute slices from overnight?  Or even test all of them, but in 5 minute chunks, so that the data structures have a better chance of fitting into memory?

Comment: :( i am a tester learning to write code, buti cant write algorithms now. I am trying to see if read line one by one , if next line matches, that will be a duplicate. with the help of your code - can we modify

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, I would use the `diff` Unix command (available on Windows as part of Cygwin, etc), and see if that addresses your need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

raise "Syntax is comp_files file1 file2" unless ARGV.length == 2

file1, file2 = ARGV

`sort #{file1} > file1_sorted.txt`
`sort #{file2} > file2_sorted.txt`

`diff file1_sorted.txt file2_sorted.txt 2>&1 > diff.txt`
puts 'Created diff.txt.'  # After running the script, view it w/less, etc.
```

Here is a similar script that uses temporary files that are automatically deleted before exiting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

raise "Syntax is comp_files file1 file2" unless ARGV.length == 2

require 'tempfile'

input_file1, input_file2 = ARGV
sorted_file1 = Tempfile.new('comp_files_sorted_1').path
sorted_file2 = Tempfile.new('comp_files_sorted_2').path

puts [sorted_file1, sorted_file2]

`sort #{input_file1} > #{sorted_file1}`
`sort #{input_file2} > #{sorted_file2}`

`diff #{sorted_file1} #{sorted_file2} 2>&1 > diff.txt`
puts 'Created diff.txt.'  # After running the script, view it w/less, etc.

# The code below can be used to create sample input files
# File.write('input1.txt', (('a'..'j').to_a.shuffle + %w(s  y)).join("\n"))
# File.write('input2.txt', (('a'..'j').to_a.shuffle + %w(s  t  z)).join("\n"))
```

Comment: In some environments you can use process substitution to avoid creating intermediate files: `diff <(sort #{file1}) <(sort #{file2})`

Comment: @Jordan If you post your comment as an answer I will vote for it.  I tried it on my Mac and it worked.  When a single shell command does what an entire Ruby script does, why use Ruby? I'd recommend putting a filename in the command so as not to confuse: `diff <(sort input1.txt) <(sort input2.txt)`.

Comment: hi all of this is working but only if the file is small < 8 M Lines. Diff errorred out when i used > 8 million  and i already used it before posting

Comment: >  i already used it before posting: It's important to include that in your original question -- see how much effort was expended because that wasn't communicated? In addition, you haven't answered a question above that would help people know what you want.  What *exactly* do you want the result to be?

Comment: I am sorry, i included more comments. Really sorry, i should have included those.

Comment: Good stuff, and great that it  works for OP, but newer  readers should be aware that creating files (especially sort outputs), require writing most/all data to a tmp file (thru the pipe/process substitution) before the final result is returned. So for these pretty large files, you need to have adequate space in the `/tmp` partition to store the data as it is being sorted. Its also lucky that in this case, it's OK to sort the data and still rely on the `diff` output. In more complex cases, it might require appending lineNo to rec, sort, and at end resort by lineNo. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is with `readlines`. This method will read the entire file and return a string. Since your file is huge, you will risk running out of memory.

To work with large files, don't read the entire contents at once, but read in pieces as needed.

Also, your algorithm has another problem since the comparison really checks whether all lines in `aFile` are included in `bFile` without actually checking for order at all. I'm not sure if that is indeed your intent.

If you really want to compare line by line and if order matters, then your comparison should be line-by-line and you don't have to read the entire file into a string. Use the `gets` method instead, which by default returns the next line in a file or `nil` at EOF.

Something like this:

```
aFile.each do |e|
  if e != bFile.gets
    p 'Able to get differences:' + e.to_s
    fileR.write('Does not Include:' + e)
  end
end
```

On the other hand, if you really want to find if all lines in a are in b, regardless of order, you can do a nested loop, where for each line in a, you iterate all lines of b. Make sure to return on first match to speedy things up since this will be a really expensive operation, but the `include` call is also expensive so it's probably a tie IMO with the exception of the file IO overhead.